# Topological conjugacy of dynamical systems knowing all there periodic orbits

Tags: general-topology, functions, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-dynamics

Let's assume we have a discrete dynamical system with $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$x_t=f(x_{t-1}), \text{ where } f: M \rightarrow M \text{ continuous} $$
Let's further assume we know all its cyclic points, i.e. we know all
$$x^*=f^k(x^*) \quad \forall k$$.

Is this information enough to know the topological conjugacy class of the dynamical system?

---

If this information is not enough, would it be enough if we further know that the map only has finitely many cyclic points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot infer the topological conjugacy class of $f$ even if there only many finitely many cyclic points.

A counterexample is given by circle rotations $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$.
If the rotation angle is irrational, the dynamical system has no cyclic points.
But any two circle rotations of different angles are not topologically conjugate.

You may consult Wikipedia [1] for starters or chapter 7.1 in the textbook "Introduction to Dynamical Systems" by Brin and Stuck.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number

Comment: Thanks for the nice counter example. This seems to hold due to the topology of the circle. Would the conjugacy class be determined if I add that the space must be simply connected?

Comment: The underlying space being simply connected is still not sufficient. You can construct essentially the same counterexample on the sphere $S^2$ instead of the circle $S^1$. Namely, you consider the systems that rotate the sphere by an irrational angle around a fixed axis. The restriction of these systems to the great circle in the plane orthogonal to that axis are exactly the circle rotations. Some technicality needs to be dealt with in this reduction, but the idea is the same. I can expand my answer if you would like to see that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You don't need to expand your answer. But it seems that you know a lout about DS. I would be more interested if you know what additional information one needs besides all cyclic points to get the topological conjugacy class. Or in general what the minimal set of information is to identify the topological conjugacy class. I can also open a new question about this